# Domain appears taken when searched from a different host, but whois says 'No match'

Tags: domain-registration, whois, domain-registrar

I have recently registered a new `.name` domain. It is just `myfirstname.name`, something like `nanda.name`.

My debit card has been billed, but my domain control panel doesn't show any information regarding the new domain.

I have raised a ticket with their support and there is no response yet. It's been 3 days.

I checked some other registrars and almost all of them say that `nanda.name` is taken, but when I search whois either from my command line or the numerous whois web services, I get `No match` as answer each time.

What gives?

PS : I should add that this registrar's support is known to suck, which, by the time I found, is a bit late.

Comment: can you access the domain ?

Comment: No I cannot access the domain. It is not reachable at all.

Comment: Please tell us the name of the registrar so we can avoid it!

Comment: hehe, this is a good one Cyberherbalist :)

Comment: It is a popular-by-seo Indian web host. :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official WHOIS server is **[whois.nic.name](https://whois.nic.name/)**. Check your domain there. Other services might take some time until they're up to date (depending on their implementation).

Because you registered a second level name, you should pay attention that it is not listed as "shared" (otherwise only third level domain names could be registered).

Comment: What should be entered as a password to check my domain in `whois.nic.name`?

Comment: Okay, password is only required in the Detailed results tab. I still get a `No match` result.